# Can not link data to SharePoint list from Access

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm working with Sharepoint 2013 & MS Access 2013, till yesterday, everything still good, I click on the button `Open with Access`, input data, share to site...
BUT TODAY, the button `Open with Access` has been disabled (i dont know why) so I must create a DB and connect to Sharepoint site through `External Data/More/Sharepoint list`. But when I input the link http://10.x.x.x/MySite/ to `Specifyy a Sharepoint site:` text box, i get the error message "Microsoft Access could not connect to the site you specified. Verify the address of the site or contact your site administrator". What can I do to connect to the site with MS Access again?